# What is the RFC 822 format for the email addresses?

Tags: email, character, email-validation, rfc822

I have to make a regular expression for the email addresses (RFC 822) and I want to know which characters are allowed in the local part and in the domain.

I found this https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6.1 but I don't see that it says which are the valid characters.

Comment: See my StackOverflow answer to a similar question (including regex for validation) here: [Email - RFC 2821, 2822 Compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression/51332395#51332395)

Answer (score 9):

According to RFC 822, the local part may contain any ASCII character, since `local-part` is defined using `word`, which is defined as `atom / quoted-string`; `atom` covers most ASCII characters, and the rest can be written in a `quoted-string`. There are syntactic restrictions, but obeying them, any ASCII character can be used.

On similar grounds, RFC 822 allows any ASCII character in the `domain` part.

On the other hand, RFC 822 was obsoleted in 2001 by [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2822), which in turn was obsoleted in 2008 by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5322). The status of RFCs can be checked from the RFC Editor’s [RFC database](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc.html).